# How do I create Google Extension Apps, just like those in the chrome://apps/?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created some Chrome extensions for fun but later I found some app in the `chrome://apps/` tab.

I tried to open their `manifest.json` and find this segment:

```
"app": {
   "launch": {
      "web_url": "https://www.***.com/"
   },
   "urls": [ "https://www.***.com/" ]
},
```

But I couldn't find any related documentation online.

Is there any reference for this?

Thanks

Comment: Asking for off-site resources, tutorials, libraries, or tools recommendation is off-topic in here

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's here. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps

But you should carefully consider to use this because:

> Important: Chrome will be removing support for Chrome Apps on Windows, Mac, and Linux.